# Facebook Graph Api not returning all photos

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

On website I need to display photos from FB album. I am reading the result of Graph API, but this result does not contain all photos in the album.

The Graph result is http://graph.facebook.com/10152930104832819/photos , album is here https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.10152930104832819.1073741960.210476192818&type=3 . Can anyone point me what could be wrong in here? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sometimes facebook graph-API doesn't return all the results.

you can try to change some "search" parameters, sometimes it works. for example, try to change the limit of returned results, like this:

```
GET /v2.5/me/photos?limit=1000 HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.facebook.com
```

Answer (score 2):

The rest of the photos are at this link [http://graph.facebook.com/v1.0/10152930104832819/photos?pretty=1&limit=25&after=MTAxNTMwNTE0MDI2MTc4MTk\u00253D](http://graph.facebook.com/v1.0/10152930104832819/photos?pretty=1&limit=25&after=MTAxNTMwNTE0MDI2MTc4MTk%5Cu00253D)

You have to keep note of the paging at the bottom of the call